# Bootstrap Alert does not fade and Sliding up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap alerts are not working with CSS animation class `fadeout`. As mentioned in BS documentation `closed.bs.alert` does: `This event is fired when the alert has been closed (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).`
But I want to fade and sildeUp the alert.

### JavaScript

```
$('.alert').each(function(index, el) {
   $(this).on('closed.bs.alert', function(){
     $(this).addClass('animated fadeOut')
   })
});
```

Can I use jQuery `fadeOut` method and `slideUp` to do the work?

### HTML

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <p><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <strong>Success Message ! </strong>You have successfully registered</p>
</div>
```

Comment: _"But i want to fade and sildeUp the alert."_ Fade and slide up native `alert` , or modal ? Can create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http::/jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Not certain a native alert can be have fade or slide up effect applied ? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Comment: Can create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- bind event at `close.bs.alert`
- remove bootstrap animation and use your own

please see code below.

```js
// bind event at 'close.bs.alert'
$('.alert').on('close.bs.alert', function(e) {

  // stop Bootstrap animation
  e.stopPropagation();

  // Use my own animation
  $(this).closest('.alert')
    .animate({
      height: 'toggle',
      opacity: 'toggle'
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <p><i class="fa fa-check"></i>  <strong>Success Message ! </strong>You have successfully registered</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```